# Encrypt/Decrypt binary mp3 with mcrypt, missing mimetype

Tags: php, mime-types, binaryfiles, mcrypt

I have a script that read a mp3 file and encrypt it, I want to be able to decrypt this file and convert it to base64 so it can play in html5.

Key 1 will be stored on the page and static, key2 will be unique for each file, for testing I used:

```
$key1 = md5(time());
$key2 = md5($key1.time());
```

Here is my encode php code :

```
//Get file content
$file = file_get_contents('test.mp3');
//Encrypt file
$Encrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key1, $file, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $key2);
$Encrypt = trim(base64_encode($Encrypt));
//Create new file
$fileE = "test.mp3e"; $fileE = fopen($file64, 'w') or die("can't open file");
//Put crypted content
fwrite($fileE, $Encrypt);
//Close file
fclose($fileE);
```

Here is the code that doesnt work (decoded file is same size, but no mimetype):

```
//Get file content
$fileE = file_get_contents('test.mp3e');
//Decode
$fileDecoded = base64_decode($fileE);
//Decrypt file
$Decrypt = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key1, $fileDecoded, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $key2);
$Decrypt = trim($Decrypt);
//Create new file
$file = "test.mp3"; $file = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
//Put crypted content
fwrite($file, $Decrypt);
//Close file
fclose($file);
```

Comment: What do you mean "no MIME type"? Is the decrypted file identical to the original (does it produce an identical hash)? How do you determine it has "no MIME type"?

Comment: what is the value of the variable $file64 ?

Comment: @ deceze : While comparing hashes, I noticed my... md5(time()) for the key, encrypting the file and then decrypting the file... regenerate the md5(time()) hash, so I get a file with the same size as the original, but not the good content in it... Feeling stupid - You solved my problem :)

Comment: @ Christopher Pelayo: Few people have access to the files on the server and i dont want ""bad"" files to be in hand of ""bad"" people :)

Comment: @ Christopher Pelayo: sorry, typo, it should be $fileE

Comment: okies try to check my answer not sure about it cause I don't know what value you have assigned on the variable $file64 but I think it would still be better to try checking it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your pointing on the wrong file take a look on this code:

```
$fileE = "test.mp3e"; $fileE = fopen($file64, 'w') or die("can't open file");
```

Then check the file your trying to decrypt:

```
$fileE = file_get_contents('test.mp3e');
```

I think you have a mistake on the filename. Not sure wasn't able to see what the value of variable $file64 is. Though you have assigned the filename value on $fileE value as "test.mp3e" it would still get what you defined on $file64 though. :)